# Backbone - Change tagName on condition

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to switch the tagName of a Backbone view based on a condition.

I initially thought I would be able to set a default tagName of say 'div' (I realize this is the default), then in the view's initialize function, check for the condition and change the tagName but this unfortunately didn't work.

Here is my view code (written in coffeescript):

```
  class Test.Views.ListView extends Backbone.View
    attributes: {"data-role": "listview"}
    className: 'row'
    tagName: 'div'
    initialize: ->
      if @options and @options.device == "mobile"
        @template = "/app/templates/mobile/test/test.html" 
        @tagName = 'ul'
```

With this code, the tagName does not change, it always remains a div. While the template is switched correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.  Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The view's `el` is set up before `initialize` is called. From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> **el** `view.el`
>
> All views have a DOM element at all times (the **el** property)...

So all view instances always have an `el` and in particular, `el` is created from the view's `tagName` before `initialize` is called. You're trying to change `@tagName` in your constructor but `el` already exists so it is too late for a simple `@tagName` change to have any effect.

You can use [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to change the view's `el`:

> **setElement** `view.setElement(element)`
>
> If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use **setElement**, which will also create the cached `$el` reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

Something like this:

```
initialize: ->
  if @options and @options.device == "mobile"
    @template = "/app/templates/mobile/test/test.html" 
    @setElement(@make('ul', _(@attributes).extend(class: @className)))
```

You could also set `@tagName = 'ul'` if you wanted but it won't matter since `tagName` is only used when instantiating a view. Also, `@options` should always be there so you don't have to check it and since you're using CoffeeScript, the accessor variant of the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) would be more idiomatic if you wanted to check it anyway:

```
if @options.?device == 'mobile'
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/j4mSu/1/

Comment: I think it must be: `attrs =  _.extend(@attributes, {'class': @className});
    @setElement(@make('ul',  attrs), true);` because there is attributes property.

Comment: One question, what is @make? where did you find it? Thanks.

Comment: @user1248256: Right, thanks for that, I overlooked the `@attributes`.

Comment: @Mitciv: `make` is a utility function that comes with all Backbone views: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-make

Comment: @Mitciv, If you're interesting about this methods I suggest you look at the source; it's simple: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-154

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using view.setElement(element) directly instead of setting the tag name?

Answer (score 1):

As of backbone 0.9.9 (which did not exist when this question was asked), the tagName field can be a function. This can be used to choose the tagName dynamically when the view is created.