# Updating enclosing tag class in Marionette.ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Marionette.ItemView that uses a CSS class to style new items differently:

```
class Happenator.Views.Option extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
  tagName: 'li'
  className: =>
    return 'new' if @model.isNew()
  initialize: ->
    @bindTo @model, "change", -> @render()
```

When the model is saved and updated, everything refreshes but the 'new' class remains on the 'li'. Is there a good way to update the enclosing tags' class on updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the 'new' class remains on the 'li', because in fact Backbone uses the `className` property only right before an initialize method call. Take a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804763/1248256) for more explanations.

But why don't use jQuery `.toggleClass` or `.removeClass`? Something like

```
render: =>
    @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON()))
    unless @model.isNew()
        @$el.removeClass('new')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GX8WJ/21/

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thinking about my options, I now think the cleanest may be to avoid setting the class on $el and instead set if via a conditional in the template.